# at Connection.query (/var/www/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Hi so i am trying to start a script using

```
pm2 start unencrypted.js && pm2 logs
```

and evrytime i do it i would get this error

```
/root/.pm2/logs/unencrypted-error.log last 15 lines:
0|unencryp |     at Connection.query (/var/www/html/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:198:25)
0|unencryp |     at createRaffle (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:3335:10)
0|unencryp |     at checkCurrentRaffles (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:3724:13)
0|unencryp |     at Timeout._onTimeout (/var/www/html/socket/unencrypted.js:3647:26)
0|unencryp |     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
0|unencryp |     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
0|unencryp |     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
0|unencryp |     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
0|unencryp |   code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
0|unencryp |   errno: 1364,
0|unencryp |   sqlMessage: 'Field \'winner_tradeid\' doesn\'t have a default value',
0|unencryp |   sqlState: 'HY000',
0|unencryp |   index: 0,
0|unencryp |   sql:
0|unencryp |    'INSERT INTO raffles SET tipul = 0, item_id = \'0\' , item_name = \'500 Coins\', item_image = \'http://192.168.1.12/vendor/img/icon-coins.png\', item_price = 500, slots = 2\n    , price_per_ticket = 270, hash = \'0d5ed54011decefeca62ecd5cc724377ca250b925620e2e2713169da3bc7fb6a\', secrets = \'qCsD7ugmdxpEeVlg-P5RCLD3FZBohtfBp\', secret_winner = \'qCsD7ugmdxpEeVlg\'\n    , secret_number = 0, time = 1612376825' }
```

and i dont know how to fix it maybe you guys can help me

Comment: If you read the error sqlMessage what do you think it means? hint what value will winner_tradeid get? How is it defined?

Comment: i think i need to add a default value to it

Comment: like define to and 0

Comment: Or declare it as accepting the absence of a value -> `NULL`.